# How to build ohNet for iOS?

Tags: ios, makefile, cross-compiling, upnp

I am trying to build the ohNet UPnP stack from openhome.org for execution on the iPhone and iPhoneSimulator. I have seen in various places on the web that there is a port to iOS, and indeed there is some reference to iOS building in the Makefile. After some editing of the $DEVROOT and $SDKROOT paths, I can compile many of the sources, but the build halts with error at:

```
g++ -pthread  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/ -arch armv6  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/system -shared -shared-libgcc  -o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/libohNet.dylib Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Ascii.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/AsyncC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/AsyncPrivate.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Bonjour.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Buffer.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Discovery.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Debug.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Converter.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceCore.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceStd.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceDvCore.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceDvStd.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceDvC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceUpnpCore.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceUpnpC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpDeviceUpnpStd.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiDevice.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiDeviceDv.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiDeviceUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiService.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiStack.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpiSubscription.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpProxy.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpProxyC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/CpServiceC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvDevice.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvDeviceStd.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvDeviceC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviDevice.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvInvocationC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvInvocationStd.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviProtocolUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviProviderSubscriptionLongPoll.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvOpenhomeOrgSubscriptionLongPoll1.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviServer.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviServerUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviServerWebSocket.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviService.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviStack.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviSubscription.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DviPropertyUpdateCollection.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvProvider.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvProviderC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvServerUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DvServerUpnpC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DeviceXml.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Error.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/EventUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Exception.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Fifo.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Http.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DNSCommon.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/DNSDigest.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/mDNS.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/uDNS.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/MdnsPlatform.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/MdnsProvider.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Maths.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Md5.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/NetworkAdapterList.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Network.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Parser.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Printer.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/ProtocolUpnp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Queue.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/RefCounter.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Service.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/ServiceC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/sha1.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Ssdp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/SsdpDv.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Stack.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Stream.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Subscription.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Thread.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Timer.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Uri.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/XmlParser.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/XmlFetcher.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNet.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetCp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetDv.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetCombined.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetC.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetCCp.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetCDv.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OhNetCCombined.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/OsWrapper.o Build/Obj/Mac/arm/Release/Os.o 
llvm-g++-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [ohNetDll] Error 255
```

I cannot understand why the build process wants to build ohNetDll for this platform, nor how to opt out of that section/target. Dynamic libraries are not supported for iOS Apps and certainly not dlls which are native to Windows.

If you have built/ported/used ohNet on iOS can you please advise how to do it? I wanted to post this question on the ohNet forum, but I am unable to register (because I haven't submitted a security question even though there is nowhere to do so on the form!).

The source, documentation and API guide all look very promising for ohNet, so I am hoping you can advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "After some editing of the $DEVROOT and $SDKROOT paths, I can compile
>   many of the sources..."

For iPhoneOS Platform, set the following environment variables.

```
export ROOTDIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
export PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
export MAX_VERSION="5.1"
export DEVROOT=${ROOTDIR}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=${DEVROOT}/SDKs/${PLATFORM}${MAX_VERSION}.sdk
```

Then, in the root directory of the source, in the file "Makefile", locate the following section and ensure it looks the same as this one:

```
ifeq ($(MACHINE), Darwin)
ifeq ($(mac-arm),1)
    # Darwin, ARM -> iOS
    platform ?= iOS
    linkopts_ohNet =    
    devroot=$(DEVROOT)
    sdkroot=$(SDKROOT)
    platform_cflags = -I$(sdkroot)/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$(sdkroot)/usr/include/ -I/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc -miphoneos-version-min=2.2 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $(sdkroot) -DPLATFORM_MACOSX_GNU -DPLATFORM_IOS -I$(sdkroot)/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv6-apple-darwin10/ 
    # It seems a bit weird that iOS uses a sub-dir of Build/Obj/Mac, is that deliberate? --AW
    osbuilddir = Mac/arm
    objdir = Build/Obj/Mac/arm/$(build_dir)/
    platform_linkflags = -L$(sdkroot)/usr/lib/ -arch armv7  -L$(sdkroot)/usr/lib/system
    compiler = $(devroot)/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2  -arch armv7 -isysroot $(SDKROOT) -o $(objdir)
    # No support for linking Shared Objects for ARM MAC
    # link = $(devroot)/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2  -pthread -Wl $(platform_linkflags)
    ar = $(devroot)/usr/bin/ar rc $(objdir)
    native_only = yes
```

The key points here are:

1. The $DEVROOT and $SDKROOT are correct for your version of the iOS SDK.
2. The variable $native_only is set to yes. This avoids error and early exit when make tries (and inevitably fails) to build ohNetDll on the Mac host machine.

Then, in a terminal, in the source root directory (i.e the one containing Makefile) type:

```
make mac-arm=1
```

Hope this helps...

Doug